# td align right not working in html code

Tags: html, html-table

I have a form and I want the labels to be aligned to the right. When I say "labels", I mean the text to the left of the form input boxes.  I have those in separate  elements.  When I type `<td align="right">` it is not working. What do I have to change?

Full Html code:

```html
<h3 align="center"><font size="5">LifeLink PSU Mentor Application</font><br><font size="4">Please fill out all requried fields</font></h3>



<body bgcolor="lightblue">
  <style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
      /* border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;*/
    }
    th,
    td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }
    table#Mentorinfo {
      width: 60%;
    }
    table#header th {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
    .medium-btn {
      background-color: #99CCFF;
      color: #000000;
      width: 70px;
      height: 30px;
    }
  </style>

  <form id="Mentorinfo">
    <table border="1" id="Mentorinfo" align="center" style="background:white;">

      <tr>
        <td width="50%" align="right">PSU ID:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="PSUID" />
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right">First Name:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="FirstName" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right">Last Name:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="LastName" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right">Age:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" name="Age">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="right">Phone number:
          <br>***-***-****</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="MenTel" pattern=".*^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$.*" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>PSU email:
          <br>Example qwe1234@psu.edu</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="Email" pattern=".*^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$.*" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Semester and year applying for?:
          <br>Example: Spring 2015</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="SemYear" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Major(s):
          <br>separate majors with commas</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="Major" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Which college are you from?:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="CollegeName" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Do you want to become a mentor or intern?:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="VolType" value="mentor" />Mentor
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="VolType" value="intern" />Intern
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Are you doing this for major requirements or class credit?:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="ForMentoring" value="Major requirement" />Major requirements
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ForMentoring" value="Class credit" />Class credit
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="ForMentoring" value="Neither, just want to help out" />Neither, just want to help out!
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>If for class credit, what class it for?</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="ClassTitle" />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>How many hours are you required to complete?</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="RequiredHours" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Your organization name (if applicable)</td>
        <td>

          <input type="text" name="Org" />

        </td>



      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>If from an organization, how many hours are required?
          <br>(if applicable)</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="OrgReqHrs" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>What skills or experiences can you bring?</td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="Skills" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>What extra-curricular activites are you involved in?</td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="ExtraCurricular" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Any additional information you would like share with us?</td>
        <td>
          <textarea name="AddDetails" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><b><br><center>Mentor/Volunteer Agreement</center></b>


          <ul>
            <li>I agree not to dispense any medication (Tylenol, etc) to students</li>
            <li>I agree to be responsible about attending. If I cannot fulfill my obligation, i will call in a timely manner.</li>
            <li>I agree to avoid activities/places prohibited by the program or in the student's individual permission form. (e.g going to fraternities/sororities, dorm rooms, etc)</li>
            <li>I agree to maintain language, attire, conduct, etc., appropriate for working with high school students.</li>
            <li>I agree to adhere to professional guidelines regarding confidentiality.</li>
            <li>I agree to embrace the spirit and philosophy of the program, e.g developing independence, social relationships, etc.</li>

          </ul>
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td colspan="2">
          <center>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Agreement" value="1">I Aggree to the above terms of mentorship.</center>
          <br>
        </td>




      </tr>

    </table>

    <center>

      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button medium-btn" onclick="google.script.run
                                         .withSuccessHandler(Success)
                                         .withFailureHandler(Failed)
                                         .processForm(document.forms[0]);" />



      <input float="center" type="button" value="Clear" class="button medium-btn" onclick="clear()" />
    </center>



  </form>



  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="result" align="center"></div>
  <p>
  </p>


  <script>
    function Success(firstName) {

      var divElement = document.getElementById("result");
      divElement.innerHTML = '<font color="green" > Your application was successfully added to the database!</font>';

    }

    function Failed(FailedReturned) {

      var divElement = document.getElementById("result");
      divElement.innerHTML = '<font color="red" >' + FailedReturned + '</font>';


    }

    function clear() {

      document.forms[0].reset();

    }


  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Why  do you have all those errors in the HTML? A `<h3>` before the `<body>`, a `<style>` inside the `<body>`, `<center>` inside `<b>` etc etc. What were you thinking? Not to mention that half those elements were deprecated decades ago and are now officially obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

remove the css property `text-align:left` from

```
 td {
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
    }
```

like this

```
td {
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

and add individually foreach td
[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mbo1peqf/)